# Extension Theorem; Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Suppose λ is the Lebesgue measure, $A_0$ is the $\sigma$-algebra of Lebesgue measurable sets, and E a non-measurable set with $0=λ_\ast(E)$ , $λ^\ast(E)=1$ ,  $\nu(E) = \gamma$.

let $ \lambda [(A ∩ E) ∪ (B ∩ (X \setminus E))] = γλ(A) + (1 − γ)λ(B)$.
 Where $A,B\in A_0$.

then by extension theorem this is a measure on the $\sigma$-algebra $\sigma(A_0 ∪ \{E\})$.

For me is not easy to see that this is a measure. Clearly, not hard to see that for empty set this is zero and also that this is non-negative. But I don't know how to prove that it satisfies the additivity property.

$\textbf{My attempt}$ to prove the additivity,  but not sure if it is correct;

let $\cup D_i$ be the disjoint union of the sets where $D_i \in \sigma(A_0 ∪ \{E\})$ , (i.e. $D_j\cap D_i = \emptyset $). By definition we have that

$$D_i      = (A_i ∩ E) ∪ (B_i ∩ E^c)$$ 
$$\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} D_i = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\left[(A_i ∩ E) ∪ (B_i ∩  E^c) \right]$$
$$\lambda(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} D_i) = \lambda(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}\left[\underbrace{(A_i ∩ E) ∪ (B_i ∩  E^c)}_\text{disjoint}\right])$$

since $D_j\cap D_i = \emptyset \implies [(A_j ∩ E) ∪ (B_j ∩  E^c) ] \cap [(A_i ∩ E) ∪ (B_i ∩  E^c)] = \emptyset$ 
\begin{equation}
\lambda(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} D_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda(\left[\underbrace{(A_i ∩ E) ∪ (B_i ∩  E^c)}_\text{but is it $\lambda$-measurable????}\right])
\end{equation}
$$\lambda(\bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty} D_i) = \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}\lambda(D_i)$$

Comment: Well, any set $\mathcal A_0$-measurable set $A$ can be decomposed into the union of $A\cap E$ and $A\cap \bar E$, both of which are measurable in your new $\sigma$-algebra. If you have a sequence $A_i$ of such sets, their union is also an $\mathcal A_0$-measurable set, so you can apply your measure extension on both sides and see whether you get the equality.

Comment: how those sets are measurable on the new $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: Those sets are measurable in the new $\sigma$-algebra as they are intersections of sets that are measurable there.

Comment: but E is a non-measurable set with outer measure 1 and inner measure 0.

Comment: I could show that $A \cap E$ is measurable but cannot show that $B \cap E^c$ is measurable. 

tbh , I also cannot understand what is the rule of specifying outer and inner measure here for the non-measurable set E.

Comment: you can use the fact that $D_i = (D_i \cap E) \cup (D_i \cap E^c)$.